# PHP drop down menu, once clicked

Tags: php

I have created a drop down menu in php that is displayed however, when a value has been clicked, I don't know how to collect this information.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost','root','','TestTimeTableSolution');
$rows = $mydb->query("SELECT DISTINCT TeacherID FROM Teacher;")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$teachers = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    array_push($teachers, $row["TeacherID"]);
}

$dropdownMenu = "<select name='TeacherID' form='Teacher'><option value='Null' selected>All</option>";
foreach ($teachers as $topic) {
    $dropdownMenu .= "<option value='" . $topic . "'>" . $topic . "</option>";
}
$dropdownMenu .= "</select>";

echo $dropdownMenu;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"how to collect this information"_ - where you wanna collect that info? in javascript? in the next php script after a form submit?

Comment: I want to collect the name that is clicked on as a string

Comment: yeah, but _where_

Comment: i don't know what I need to write or where i need to put it to collect what is clicked on

Comment: i want it to be dynamic so as soon as the user clicks on something the relevant information will pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, *"i want it to be dynamic so as soon as the user clicks on something the relevant information will pop up"*, it sounds like you will probably want to use Ajax/JavaScript (I will demonstrate a simple [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) example, notating for clarity):

```
<?php
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost','root','','TestTimeTableSolution');
?>
<html>
<!-- Add the jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Act when the document is ready
$(function(){
    // listen for the select to change
    $('select[name=TeacherID]').on('change',function(){
        // Run the ajax – you can also use the shortcut $.post method found at:
        // https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
        $.ajax({
            // This is the page that is going to do the data lookup/display action
            url: '/lookup.php',
            // This is how it's sending the data to that page
            type: 'post',
            // This is what is being sent ($_POST['submit'] in this case)
            data: {
                // Use $(this) to isolate the current selected element and get value (.val())
                // The value is represented as $topic in your php
                'submit': $(this).val()
            },
            // If all goes well and the page (lookup.php) returns a response
            success: function(response) {
                // Place the response into the div (see html snippet)
                $('#loadspot').text(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<?php
$rows = $mydb->query("SELECT DISTINCT TeacherID FROM Teacher;")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$teachers = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    array_push($teachers, $row["TeacherID"]);
}

$dropdownMenu = "<select name='TeacherID' form='Teacher'><option value='Null' selected>All</option>";
foreach ($teachers as $topic) {
    $dropdownMenu .= "<option value='" . $topic . "'>" . $topic . "</option>";
}
$dropdownMenu .= "</select>";

echo $dropdownMenu;
?>
<!---------------------------------------------->
<!-- THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT WILL LOAD INTO -->
<!---------------------------------------------->
<div id="loadspot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In order for this to work, you need the page `lookup.php` in the domain root (you can make it whatever/where ever you want, but you need to match in the javascript `url`):

**/lookup.php**

```
<?php
# This is what will get placed into the parent page <div id="loadspot"></div>
# Do you your php here in place of this line and return whatever "relative information" you want
print_r($_POST);
```

You should review the jQuery page I have linked to to get more information and direction for that library and make sure you use your browser's developer tools to monitor javascript errors in the console. Ideally, you want to understand all this via the documentation instead of just copy and paste and move on...

Comment: where and what do i need to add, so that the item clicked on will become the contece of a string?

Comment: Where are you going to use the string? You have to know how/where in order to tell you the best way to get it,.

Comment: I want to store it as a string so I can then query the database, using it as a condition

Comment: Ok so you have the dropdown and option might be `<option value="1234">John Doe</option>` and you are wanting to get `1234`?

Comment: Anyway, if that is the case, then what I have is an example of that, processed through ajax. The database lookup would be done on the `lookup.php` page.

Comment: yes I'm wanting to get '1234' and to store it, as I'm not quite sure what i need to write in the lookup.php page

Comment: The javascript portion that has `data: { $(this).val()` is basically sending that value as a post to the `lookup.php` page. So on that page, to get that value, you just do `$id = $_POST['submit'];` and then `$id` will be the `1234`. From there, you just do your regular database query and echo what you want, and that will be placed on page 1 in the `<div id="loadspot"></div>`

Comment: I would say, you should set up exactly as I have written it, then see what happens on your page 1. From there you will get a better idea what you should do next.

Comment: I have copied the firs section of code and the lookup.php looks like this `print_r($_POST);
$id = $_POST['submit'];
echo $id;`

Comment: but when you click on an item in the drop down menu it doesn't echo it, do I need a select button?

Comment: `$('select[name=TeacherID]').on('change',function(){` listens for the change on the drop down. Once you change, it will execute the jquery. You need to post an edit of your updated script.

Comment: so what do i then need to put to have the item selected from the drop down to be saved as a string?

Comment: Im really sorry, I'm just quite confused

Comment: Well, when you change the selection on the dropdown, the jquery listener then gets the value (`data: {submit: $(this).val()}`) and sends it to the php page (`lookup.php`) and on that page is where you do whatever you want to do with that value. I am sending it back to an `id` called `loadspot` so you need a `div` or `span` with the `id="loadspot"` so `<div id="loadspot"></div>`.